# Unable to add autocomplete feature in Cordova iOS Application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

Here is my html code for performing auto complete text box in android cordova project but it is now working where as in the fiddle it is working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>

            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
            <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
            <title>Trial App</title>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var aTags = ["Krishna", "Shubham", "Sachin", "Android", "Windows", "Himalaya", "Bahubali", "Win", "Game"];

      $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: aTags
      });


      $('#get_value').on('click', getval);

      function getval() {

        var value_inside = $("#autocomplete").val();
        alert("Value inside text box is: " + value_inside);
      }

    });

  </script>
<body>
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='autocomplete' />
<button id="get_value">get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

the link of the fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/krishlahoti/g83x5wLz/

In the fiddle i have used the same code as in the above HTML file the fiddle is working as desired but the cordova app doesn't.

Attaching a screenshot along with this question to make it more clear
[Refer this screenshot for the Cordova iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4wmg.png)

Comment: may be you forgot the "device ready" event ?

Comment: @Korr $(document).ready(function()  works same as "device ready"

Comment: No, "device ready" is different and essential to any Cordova/PhoneGap applications (look at the doc). "Device Ready" fires when Cordova has fully loaded and "document ready"  fires when DOM has fully loaded.

Comment: But the code I provided in the solution works as desired without "device ready"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research and help from my colleagues i could finally achieve to my goal.

Below is the final code that works as needed in the question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

  <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var aTags = ["Krishna", "Shubham", "Sachin", "Android", "Windows", "Himalaya", "Bahubali", "Win", "Game"];

      $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: aTags
      });


      $('#get_value').on('click', getval);

      function getval() {

        var value_inside = $("#autocomplete").val();
        alert("Value inside text box is: " + value_inside);
      }

    });

  </script>
<body>
<input type='text' title='Tags' id='autocomplete' />
<button id="get_value">get</button>
</body>
</html>
```